# CRIU for non-root users

Tags: docker, process-management, restore, checkpoint

CRIU doesn't support in non-root user environment, to my knowledge. Does anyone have got a patch for this?

-a Linux enthusiastic.

Comment: To clarify, this CRUI: https://criu.org/Main_Page ?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Sorry for less details.

Answer (score 2):

Information about the issues regarding running CRIU as non-root user is available in https://criu.org/User-mode

On LPC 2018, Google [announced](https://linuxplumbersconf.org/event/2/contributions/209/attachments/27/24/Task_Migration_at_Google_Using_CRIU.pdf) that they use CRIU in production, and explained how they perform checkpoint/restore in [non-root user environment](https://linuxplumbersconf.org/event/2/contributions/210/attachments/32/30/Securely_migrating_untrusted_workloads_with_CRIU.pdf).